# Supernatural behaviour with a facebook page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying something with facebook pages. I did the following:

1. Created a new facebook page.
2. Added 3 posts with the texts:"Hi! this is the first post of this page.","This is the second post of this page.","This is the third post of this page." respectively.
3. I did a "view source"
4. Then i clicked ctrl+f and searched for "Hi! this is the first post of this page."
5. I found it inside a span.

But the strange thing about it was that it was under a comment.Now if that is commented out,how is it being rendered by the browser?

To further investigate the issue, I did an inspect element after selecting the above text in the post. Output was:

```
<span class="userContent" data-ft="{"tn":"K"}">

    Hi! this is the  first post of this page.

</span>
```

And these were not at all commented!! So how could that happen? Is there anything supernatural about it?(cant be..)

Answer (score 1):

"view source" (ctrl-f) is showing static content loaded by the browser. "inspect element" shows the actual content after some AJAX, java script processing etc.

So no "magic" in here, you are looking at two different states of this page.

Comment: Thanks for your cool answer. I am upvoting for it. But could u guess any means by which I can track that "what" led to the state of the page under discussion?